# Visual Studio 2017: Command "setx" is not valid

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I am trying some instructions for setting an Environment variable using visual studio for [opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windowssetpathandenviromentvariable)

As per the instructions, I have to open the **command window** and run the following command in it

```
setx -m OPENCV_DIR D:\OpenCV\Build\x64\vc14
```

But doing so is resulting in an error as **Command "setx" is not valid**

How to proceed?

Comment: There is no need to set any environment variables.

Comment: That is not a happy error message.  You'd better check if c:\windows\system32\setx.exe is still there.  If it is then you need to fix the PATH.  Ask for help with that at superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

Referring [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/how-to-set-environment-variables-for-the-visual-studio-command-line) article by MS, it is clear that you need to open the **Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017.** Do so with administrative privileges.

Then run above command in it to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Run command prompt as administrator
(search cmd and when the search results are displayed, right click over the command prompt and select the "run as administrator" option.)

Then just type the command and enjoy:)